# Wordpress removing p tags when not logged in

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have been struggling to understand why my text was changing size on a daily basis and have come to realise that wordpress is stripping the P tags out of the pages every time the_content() is used.

When I am logged in to wordpress and view the site everything is perfectly fine and the P tags appear which makes my fonts much nicer. However when logged out of wordpress all P tags are stripped. the_content() is not within any conditional statements it is completely alone in the code so I can't understand why this behaviour would happen.

If anyone has an any idea on this it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this useful [Pluggin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)

After Installation:
Settings > TinyMCE Advanced > `check` the    **Stop removing the P tag .....**

Now, WordPress will not remove any paragraph tag.Hope this will help you